# Why there is need to define destructor explicitly in deletion of linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, destructor, delete-operator

In the below code we initialize the next pointer of deleted node as NULL in delete function, so why we need to explicitly define destructor in class, is there any problem with default destructor which is automatically generated by complier.
We know that destructor will delete the object without any writing any additional code for it
Why we write the extra code for destructor here.
In delete section, we have to take care of that deleted node shouldn't point anything and we did it.

So , what's need to explicitly declare the destructor in it?

```
class Node {
    public:
    int data;
    Node* next;

    //constructor
    Node(int data) {
        this -> data = data;
        this -> next = NULL;
    }

    // destructor
    ~Node() {
        int value = this -> data;
        //memory free krr rhe hain
        if(this -> next != NULL){
            delete next;
            this -> next = NULL;
        }
        cout << "memory is free for node with data" << value << endl;
    }

};

void insertAtHead(Node* &head, int data) {

    // creating new node called temp of type Node 
    Node* temp = new Node(data);
    temp -> next = head;
    head = temp;
}

void deleteNode(int position, Node* &head) {
    
    //deleting first or starting node
    if(position == 1) {
        Node* temp = head;
        head = head -> next;
        //memory free start node
        temp -> next = NULL;
        delete temp;

    } else {
        // deleting any middle node
        Node* curr = head;
        Node* prev = NULL;

        int cnt = 1;
        while(cnt <= position) {
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr -> next;
            cnt++;
        }

        prev -> next = curr -> next;
        curr -> next = NULL;
        delete curr;
    }
}

void print(Node* &head) {

    Node* temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL) {
        cout << temp -> data << " ";
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {

    Node* head = nullptr; // A list has a head
    Node* tail = head; //  a tail.

    insertAtHead(head, 10); // pass the head
    insertAtHead(head, 5);
    insertAtHead(head,15);
    print(head);  // Print the whole list
    deleteNode(1, head);
    print(head);
}
```

Comment: "We know that destructor will delete the object without...writing any additional code for it" In this case, "the object" that is automatically destroyed in the default-generated `~Node` is `next`, the `Node*` pointer, not `*next`, the `Node` object. By default, destroying a pointer does _nothing_ to the pointed-to object. If you want to delete the pointed-to object, you have to specify.

Comment: Re: "destructor will delete the object" -- no, the only way to delete an object is with `delete`. The destructor will **destroy** the object. Those are two fundamentally different things.

Answer (score 1):

" we initialize the next pointer of deleted node as NULL in delete function"

I'll assume that means "we *assign* `NULL` to the the `next` pointer of the deleted node in the *destructor*".

That assignment indeed happens, but it does absolutely nothing useful. The destructor is the last function that runs on an object. All members go away at the closing `}`, including `this->next`. That's why a default destructor does not bother with such assignments.

However, the default destructor would **not** have called `delete next;`. The default destructor would do nothing for this `Node` class. That is not necessarily a bad thing. However, it is in this example.

This code is typical of bad C++ courses. `Node` is an implementation detail of a linked list. The main class should be a `List` class. And in `List::~List` you can easily walk the list of nodes and delete each of them individually. If you write such a `List::~List`, then the default destructor of `Node` would be fine.

But somebody has to walk the list and delete all nodes. And in this design, that walk is done by a recursive Node destructor.

Comment: Alternative non-bad C++ course: `std::unique_ptr<Node> next;` instead of `Node * next;`